# I am looking for a way to fetch distinct certain column ,selecting all columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to fetch
All columns data in
selecting by distinct .
there are many columns from ID to z.

following table is example. and the actual table has many data

```
ID.name.date,a,b,c,d,e….z
----------------
1 AA 15/09/20,…(omit).
1 AA 15/09/18,…
1 AA 15/09/17,…
1 AB 15/09/10,…
2 BB 15/09/20,…
2 BB 15/09/19,…
```

```
ideal result.
ID name date,…a,b,c,d,e….z
----------------
1 AA 15/09/20,…
2 BB 15/09/20,…
```

I tried following sql

```
Select * from X_TABLE a INNER JOIN (
Select distinct  id from X_TABLE ) b on a.ID = b.ID
```

But  I found the result I tried had redundant id rows….

```
select distinct id, * from X_TABLE
```

was unable to execute.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you have, for some reason, duplicates in your ID field. But your dates make the difference.

So when you query for `select distinct id from x_table` you get

```
ID
---
1
2
```

When you query for `select distinct id, name from x_table` you get

```
ID  Name
---------
1   AA
2   BB
```

But when you add your date, which indeed identifies your dataset in combination with your id field 'select distinct id, name, date from x_table' you get

```
   ID Name Date
   ------------
   1  AA   2020-09-30
   1  AA   2020-10-01
   2  BB   2020-09-30
   2  BB   2020-10-01
```

This is distinct for the smallest granularity you asked for. If you want to display only the dataset with the newest timestamp, you should filter for that. Or add a new column "current" and use it as flag or, or, or, or... There are a lot of possibilities depending on what you really need to do.

Here is a filter query with a filter which does what you asked for:

```
select distinct id, name, date
  from x_table
 where date = to_date('2020-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Add the join criteria to do what you want it to do...

Although, from the data you provided there wouldn't be the need for the distinct operator anymore.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Sorry my English is hard to understand.

Actually X table has many columns. I am looking for the way not to write all column names in select SQL.

Comment: You should figure out what your business key is. From what I saw it is your id + date. there may be more relevant columns to your business key. then you can query for a unique row. then you won't even need a distinct operator.
`select  * from x_table where date = to_date('2020-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd')` [date in relation to my example].

Comment: date = to_date('2020-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd')  
no data is  fetched

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
select t.*
from X_TABLE t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Comment: ORA-00942  Table or view does not exist.
heppned